# problem while using awk call function in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want use awk to call `randnum` function to generate random numbers betweed 0 and 100. The script `ab.sh` is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

function randnum(){
  num=$(($RANDOM%$1))
  echo $num
}
export -f randnum

num=$(randnum 101)
echo $num

awk '
BEGIN{
  cnt=0;
  while(cnt<5){
    "randnum 101"|getline
    print $1
    cnt++
  }
}
'
```

But when I run `./ab.sh`, it has the follow error:

```
7
/bin/sh: 1: randnum: not found
```

The number 7 is generated by the function call outside the awk. But when the function called inside the awk, the `randnum` not found.

Why this happened? I try `bash ab.sh`, but still get the same error.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72935/using-bash-shell-function-inside-awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk is not Bash, it's a discrete programming language. You can't call bash functions from awk, well not that way anyway. Instead, use what [awk has](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html) to offer you:

```
awk -v seed=$RANDOM '      # seed from the shell as opposed to time based
BEGIN{
  cnt=0
  srand(seed)              # seed used with srand
  while(cnt<5){
    print int(rand()*101)  # and get a random
    cnt++
  }
}'
98
0
84
100
54
```

**Update**:

As it is Saturday and I have nothing better to do I started playing around with creating and exporting the function in bash, extracting it from the `ENVIRON[]` in GNU awk and calling bash with the function definition and a call to it:

Create the function and `export` it:

```
$ function randnum() {  num=$(($RANDOM%$1));  echo $num; }
$ export -f randnum
```

Test it:

```
$ randnum 101
1
```

The awk:

```
$ awk -v fun=randnum -v val=101 '
BEGIN {
    if(fun=="" || val=="")                                    # require values
        exit                                                  # or die
    bash_func="function " fun ENVIRON["BASH_FUNC_" fun "%%"]  # function from ENVIRON
    # print bash_func                                         # DEBUG
    cmd="bash -c \047" bash_func";" fun " " val "\47"         # form bash call
    # print cmd                                               # DEBUG
    ret=((cmd | getline line)>0?line:-1)                      # call it
    print ret                                                 # output
}'
2
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I don't quit understand, but it's very kind of you! I want to ask more a question, how can I use `sleep` in `awk` ? For some reason, I want to `sleep` 10 seconds when `cnt=2`.

Comment: No sleep command in awk, you need to borrow from the shell: `system("sleep 10")` so: `if(cnt==2)system("sleep 10")`.

Comment: actually... gawks `time` library has a `sleep` function. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Time

Comment: @EdMorton I've totally missed that one. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To play around with:

```
#!/bin/bash

function randnum {
  num=$(($RANDOM%$1))
  echo "$num"
}

if [[ $# -ne 0 ]]; then "$@"; exit; fi

awk -v script="$0" 'BEGIN{system(script " randnum 101")}'
```